# PHP Cambiar Base de datos en Foreach con boton...?

Tags: php, mysql, html-tabla

Código:

```
foreach ($conexion->query("SELECT * FROM asegurados.asegurados LIMIT 0,1000") as $row){ 
<td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit<?php echo $row[Id] ?>" value="Guardar" onclick = "<?php $query = "UPDATE asegurados.asegurados SET TelefonoV = '4123' WHERE Id = '$row[Id]' ";  if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {echo "alert('ok $row[Id]')";}?>" > 
</td>
```

Al momento de darle clic me cambia toda la base con el numero 4123... pero el mensaje pop sale ok #ID

ya le cambie el name del boton por `name#` o `name#Id` `name="submit<?php echo $row[Id] ?>")` me sigue cambiando toda la columna de TelefonoV.`

¿Tendrán alguna solucion a mi problema?

Comment: redacta mejor tu pregunta, el código dale formato con el símbolo {} así mismo explica mejor tu problema y el resultado que esperas

Comment: gracias!! si me di cuenta ya lo modifique

Comment: Todavía no termina de quedar claro tu problema, revisa como crear un [mcve] para que podamos entenderlo mejor y poder darte respuestas de calidad

Comment: No puedes ejecutar una sentencia de PHP con un evento correspondiente a Javascript como onclick. PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor. Tendrás que usar AJAX (Javascript + PHP + llamada asíncrona) para lograr lo que necesitas.

Comment: Como ya te dijeron no puedes hacerlo de esa manera debes implementar ajax pasando los parámetros y realizando el update en otro documento